# org.joda.time.LocalDate showing one day Less on Redhat (Linux) java

Tags: java, mysql, date, redhat, jodatime

I am reading date from Mysql and sending this to browser using java spring boot application.
The dates are coming correct on the Windows based deployment.
However when I deploy this on the Redhat Centos(Unix )  it is giving me 1 days less.

Reading InputDate           :  2014-07-28 00:00:00  Coming from (Mysql - Date) Field.
Output on the Windows       :  2014-07-28
Output on the Redhat(Cent)  :  2014-07-27

Here is system time zone setting.
Time zone: Europe/Dublin (IST, +0100)

Example Code:

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

```
LocalDate outPutDate = LocalDate.fromDateFields(InputDate);
System.out.println("OutpuDate:"+outPutDate);
____________________________________

On   windows   Out put Date    : 2014-07-28
On   Redhat    Out put Date    : 2014-07-27
```

Best Regards
Jai

Comment: What about the MySQL timezone Setting?

Comment: Almost certainly a time zone thing.  Probably mysql time zone but could also be user time zone, or a combination.

Comment: Check the timezone settings in MySQL. Also, switch to `java.time`. Check this notice at the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):
*Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.*

Comment: What precisely is the data type of your database column? How exactly are you retrieving the values? Show Java code, with SQL query. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your Question is currently impossible to Answer, so I am voting to close as “needs debugging details”. Furthermore, your Question is likely a duplicate.

Comment: @ Daniel Farrell   &&    @ Claus Bönnhoff   thanks for your hint.

MySql  timezone @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; was set to be system and for some reason  MySql  Installed the Redhat (Cent.)  
Was not able to sync with the  System TimeZone.

However passing the timezone explicitly  through the connection URL  Works  Ok.
  
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Dublin

Thanks for you all hint.
Regards 
Jai